# Gigabyte RTX RGB fusion light(LED) control in Linux

Tags: gpu

Is there any software(or dev repo) to control RGB fusion light control for linux/ubuntu? I got a new RTX 2080ti but the led light is always turned off.

Comment: Update: In my case, OpenRGB failed. The light didn't work in windows system either. So I got an RMA from the manufacturer to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OpenRGB** is an open source app to control RGB devices.

https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB

In the [releases page](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/releases) there are linux binaries in the `appImage` format:

- download it
- make it executable: `chmod +x OpenRGB_<version>.AppImage` (of course, `<version>` is a placeholder for the version info, replace it
- run as sudo: `sudo ./OpenRGB_<version>.AppImage`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will test on next week and adapt answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 23.04 on Gigabyte B450M DS3H WIFI-CF. I got errors trying to add the apt repository:

```
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/thopiekar/openrgb/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I had to download [the app image](https://openrgb.org/) and install [libfuse](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/8327482047772-If-you-get-an-dlopen-error-loading-libfuse-so-2-error) with `sudo apt-get  install libfuse2`; after that, I had to grant execution permissions and execute sudo with the following commands to launch the application:

```
$ chmod +x Downloads/OpenRGB_0.8_x86_64_fb88964.AppImage
$ sudo Downloads/OpenRGB_0.8_x86_64_fb88964.AppImage 

Attempting to connect to local OpenRGB server.
Connection attempt failed
Local OpenRGB server unavailable.
Running standalone.
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

[image: I like the color cycle option]
Change the mode and click any color other than black to see the light change. You may get a prompt to enter the number of LED lights at launch. I entered 50 as I have about 50 LED lights on each strip. Exiting the application does not kill the lights!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue with my RTX 2070,so far I have come across an RGB Fusion tool for the motherboard

https://github.com/tylerszabo/RGB-Fusion-Tool/blob/master/README.md

but you can change the motherboard LED's in the BIOS so..

Comment: That github repo is for windows.

Comment: well it came up in google search saying it was for linux

Comment: no... untortunately, it builds .exe files for windows

Comment: I installed RGB fusion on an old windows Hdd, set the colour and rebooted without that Hdd plugged in,it is working fine I know it is a pain in the ass way of doing it.but you could try having a look at https://www.winehq.org/